# Typescript: rest.someMethod() is not a function

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript script doesn't work with either TypeScript 4.5.5 or 4.6.4:

```html
class Thing {
    someProperty = 42;
    someMethod() {
        console.log('bar')
    }
}

function foo<T extends Thing>(x: T) {
    let { someProperty, ...rest } = x;
    rest.someMethod();
}

var t = new Thing()
t.someMethod()
foo(t)
```

I have two questions:

1. With 4.6.4 the error is `Property 'someMethod' does not exist on type 'Omit<T, "someProperty" | "someMethod">'.`  This is due to [this breaking change in TypeScript 4.6](https://Property%20%27someMethod%27%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20%27Omit%3CT,%20%22someProperty%22%20%7C%20%22someMethod%22%3E%27.).  However, could anyone explain what are unspreadable members?
2. With 4.5.5 the error is `rest.someMethod is not a function`.  Why this error before the aforementioned TypeScript 4.6 breaking change?

Answer (score 2):

**The short version:** The change in question is more of a bug fix than a breaking change in typescript 4.6, the typescript compiler did not correctly type destructured assignements when coupled with generics.

**The long version:**

Let's look at how spread works in typescript, let's grab an easier example for now

```
const t =  {
    someProperty : 42,
    someProperty2 : 4
}
const { someProperty, ...rest } = t;
```

heading to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MYG8BQSkRAWwKYAUAnEAB10KgE8YAuGAFgCYAadDLPI08qx2h1AF9UAG1yxkMDgWJkKlZjAB0KwrmgxBMRFADcqVEA) we can see that it compiles to exactly the same javascript in both 4.5 and 4.6 , you can make sure of it by swapping the versions and pasting the output to a diff editor. ( This is exactly the case for the example you provided as well )

**What does the equivalent javascript code do ?**

We don't have to understand 100% of what it does, but a quick look at it shows that it uses

```
for (var p in s)
```

As in

```
for(var property in object)
```

which would allow it to loop over properties in an object ( and not methodes ), we can check for this quickly in a js console doing and see that only properties are printed ( and not methods )

```
class Thing {
    someProperty = 42;
    property2 = 3;
    someMethod() {
        console.log('bar')
    }
}
x = new Thing();
for( var p in x){console.log(p)}
```

**Going back to a patched version of the original example**

This example should be giving us the same exact behavior from the compiler right ?

```
class Thing {
    someProperty = 42;
    someMethod() {
        console.log('bar')
    }
}
var t = new Thing()
let { someProperty, ...rest } = t;
rest.someMethod();
```

But in fact It does not as typescript 4.5 does recognize that there are no methods on the rest object and raises an error

**What's different with the example that you provided ?**

This example use destructuring directly on the object while your example used destructuring on generics.

**So where is the bug ?**

Put simply using generics made typescript not detect the "removal" of methods when destructuring, so this pesky code made it past compilation ...
The error still exists and you saw it at run time instead, which is a big deal since typescript is supposed to provide confidence ( particularly type safety ) when shipping applications ..

Hope this helped even a bit

Comment: "_loop over properties in an object ( and not methodes )_": indeed, just for reference, this is because the rest operator, like for spread, enumerates only the _own_ properties, hence it excludes the prototype chain, which is where the class methods are stored.